# Why wont my follower steal items?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In sky rim I use the glitch where if you tell a follower to pick up something it doesn't affect their inventory space but all of them refuse stealing items.

Comment: Do you mean that you order a follower to take something and they won't, or are you trying to get them to pickpocket? Followers can't pickpocket, and some followers have a morality setting such that they won't commit any crimes. What followers are you talking about?

Comment: They wont pick items up

Comment: Which followers have you tried?

Comment: Lydia Serena and the guy from morthal

Comment: That’s weird, because Lydia should be willing to commit crimes for you. What happens if you tell her to steal something? And if the guy from Morthal is Valdimar or Benor, he should be willing to commit crimes too.

Comment: No they both say that "I can't do that" or "no,sorry"

Comment: I’ll try it in my game. Seems like it should work.

Comment: She won't commit crimes. Which is weird, because she's a vampire...

Comment: I just ordered Lydia to steal and murder, and she did it. I don't know of a way to change an NPC's morality in the console, but I don't know why Lydia won't steal for you. Will she commit murders if you ask her to? Like ask her to attack a guard or something. You can check her morality in the console by clicking on her and typing `getav morality`, but it won't let you change it. It should be set to 0 (any crime).

Comment: Also, what if you ask her to steal something else? If she can't figure out how to walk to the item, she'll probably say she can't do what you ask. The NPCs aren't always very good at navigating.

Answer (score 8):

Different followers have different morality levels. If your follower's morality is "no crime", then they won't steal items for you. To see which followers are willing to steal, browse [this list of followers](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers) at UESP and look for followers with any morality other than 3 (no crime).

Followers willing to commit crimes include anyone from the College of Winterhold, the Dark Brotherhood, all hirelings, and all housecarls.

Comment: OK appreciate the help